# Validating Method is not Called on button click C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to programming and have little programming experience, build a WinForm application that has 5 text boxes, write a method ValidateTextBoxForAlphabet() for validating text only on the first 3 textboxes and I write another method for checking the numbers only, I called ValidateTextBoxForAlphabet on button click and that is successfully called but ValidateBatch() method does not call on button click.

On Button Click:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ValidateTextBoxForAlphabet(textBox1);
        ValidateTextBoxForAlphabet(textBox2);
        ValidateTextBoxForAlphabet(textBox3);
        textBox4.Text = string.Concat(textBox4.Text.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
        ValidateBatch(textBox5);

    }
```

These are my both methods:

```
 public void ValidateTextBoxForAlphabet(TextBox tb)
        {
            if(!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(tb.Text, "^[a-zA-Z ]"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Full Name, Father Name and University name can't accept numbers..." , "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK , MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }

 public void ValidateBatch(TextBox tx)
    {
        if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(tx.Text, "[^0-9]"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Batch contain only NUMBERS..", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            //textBox5.Text = textBox5.Text.Remove(textBox5.Text.Length - 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check again your Regex in `ValidateBatch()`. Does it look like the other?

Comment: thanks! problem with my Regex pattern..

Comment: Who would have guessed ;P

Comment: can you please guide me on another thing? how do I enter the batch in xxxx-xxxx format? like if someone graduates from 2015 to 2019 it will automatically take input as 2015 - 2019 or convert it to that format on the button click?

Comment: Note that it might be better for usability to inform the user as soon as he enters an invalid input. For example by attaching an eventHandler to TextChanged, check if the text is valid, and provide some indication for invalid format, like a red border.

Comment: @JonasH can you please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: [This seem to be a decent guide for validation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-use-validation-in-windows-form-application)

Answer (score 0):

just as @JonasH you validation will result to problems and bad experience to the user and hard to know where the error is coming from try validation on textBox1_TextChanged event this way use knows what is being entered is not allowed.

```
   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ValidateTextBoxForAlphabet(textBox1);
    }
```